# Scrape dynamic HTML (YouTube comments)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, dynamic-html

With Beautiful Soup and Request Library I am able to scrape HTML content, but not what loads by JavaScript or AJAX calls.

How do I mimic this through my Python script? Because YouTube comments load when we scroll the page. I found 2 methods; one using Selenium and another using lxml requests, which I couldn't understand a bit.

Example ([this is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFPMz36std4)):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFPMz36std4'
response = requests.get(url)
page_html = response.content
#print page_html

page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")
print page_soup
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **We can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: you'll have to use a browser instance, like phantomjs or headless chrome to load the page in and render the dynamic content.

Comment: 'which i could't understand a bit': That's your essential difficulty, right there. It may well be possible to do what you want using selenium. However, this is not a tutorial site. You will need to go and find one of those and learn enough to write some code that attempts to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use selenium :

Here is a trick , Youtube only load comments when you scroll just down of video , if you scroll bottom or elsewhere, comments will not load , so first scroll to that down part and wait for loading comments after that scroll to bottom or whenever you want :

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFPMz36std4')

driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(1, 500);')

#now wait let load the comments
time.sleep(5)

driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(1, 3000);')



comment_div=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contents"]')
comments=comment_div.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')
for comment in comments:
    print(comment.text)
```

some part of output:

```
#can't post full output its too long
I love Kygo's Stranger Things and Netflix's Stranger Things <3
Stranger Things, Kygo and OneRepublic, could it be better?
Amazing Vibe!!!!!!!!!
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Using Selenium would do the trick.

Though I have a different way of scrolling down. This function will help you to scroll down by calling regularly javascript and check whether the height of the window changed between the actual and previous scroll down.

```
def scrollDown(pause, driver):
    """
    Function to scroll down till end of page.
    """
    import time
    lastHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(pause)
        newHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if newHeight == lastHeight:
            break
        lastHeight = newHeight

# Main Code
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Instantiate browser and navigate to page

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFPMz36std4')
scrollDown(6, driver)

# Page soup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
```

Comment: can we do it without using selenium (without opening browser and scrolling down) , like scrapping all the comments of a video

Comment: You should consider youtubes own api that enables you to pull this kind of data easily. Read more here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#usage